# How can I write a junit test to that is dependent on index page?

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

I have a application, using java, thymeleaf, and springboot. On the home page localhost:8080 users must enter a value to be redirected to the second page "localhost:8080/getValues"

How can I write a junit test so that I can test the expected values? Currently my tests are coming up as 404 page not found because it is dependent on the value that user inputs on the home page.

**Test**

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {

    this.mockMvc.perform(get("/"))
    .andExpect(status().isOk())
    .andExpect(view().name("index"))
    .andDo(print());
     //test passes
}

@Test
public void testVals() throws Exception {

    this.mockMvc.perform(post("getValues"))
        .andExpect(status().isNotFound()) //passes
        .andExpect(model().attributeExists("webHist")); //fails //no modelandviewfound

}
```

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView index(Locale locale) throws MalformedURLException {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("index");

        return model;
    }

@RequestMapping(value = "/getValues", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView getValues(Info  info) throws MalformedURLException {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("getValues");
        model.addObject("userID", info.userID());

        Customer custinfo = index.readXML(info.userID());
        model.addObject("custinfo", custinfo); 

        model.addObject("webHist", Web_HistoryRepo.getAll(info.userID()));

       return model;
    }
```

Comment: could you show some code how the controllers looks like?

Comment: @pezetem I added my controller, Can you tell me how would I be able to change this multi-page logic to a SPA? I think If I change it to a SPA it would remove the dependency

Answer (score 0):

About the unit test, you are not sending the `Info  info`
you are missing the content() in your unit, it should something like

```
 this.mockMvc.perform(post("getValues"))
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .content(INFO_IN_JSON_FORM)
        .andExpect(status().isNotFound()) //passes
        .andExpect(model().attributeExists("webHist"));
```

if it still does not work add `.andDo(print())` to the end of the test, so that you will receive more details about result.

Next I do not how your whole Controller looks like, if it is annotated with @RestController, if not you should add @RequestBody to the getValues() method so that Info would be mapped from Json.

If it comes to the SPA, you do not return ModelAndView, but Json responses, and your frontend interprets it.

Comment: .content does not work. I tried importing MediaType. but Errors appears. "APPLICATION_JSON  cannot be resolved or is not a field"
import org.springframework.http

Comment: My controller has the annotation of @Controller. If I don't use ModelAndView What is the process? Can you provide me an url where I can convert this to an SPA.

Comment: for the SPA you can try with angular tutorial (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/), i believe that you are using JSP at your code and the SPA with it is not possible

Comment: I am using Thymeleaf, Java, Spring-boot, and angularjs. No JSP.

Comment: ok, so why you are using ModelAndView then? You should call some endpoint from angularJS, and in response receive Json from Spring Boot

Comment: because I am new and ModelAndView worked and allowed me to display values in the UI. I will try your method. Thank you.